# Nodelet crashes at launch

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to launch the Novatel gps driver from: [here](https://github.com/swri-robotics/novatel_gps_driver) .

I built it using catkin_create_pkg + catkin_make and not by catkin_tool. does that matter?
It did compile with no errors, but when I launch it I get the errors:

> [ERROR] [1514730037.320611149]: Failed
> to load nodelet [/novatel] of type
> [novatel_gps_driver/novatel_gps_nodelet]
> even after refreshing the cache:
> According to the loaded plugin
> descriptions the class
> novatel_gps_driver/novatel_gps_nodelet
> with base class type nodelet::Nodelet
> does not exist. Declared types are
> ..... long list
>
> [ERROR] [1514730037.320666606]: The
> error before refreshing the cache was:
> According to the loaded plugin
> descriptions the class
> novatel_gps_driver/novatel_gps_nodelet
> with base class type nodelet::Nodelet
> does not exist. Declared types are
> ..... long list

I have googled this error and tried plenty of answers but none worked. Also, none was really the exact same problem, or for much older versions of ROS. Does anyone know the answer to fixing this / has the time to try and install it themselves so I can see if its only my PC?

I'm also not sure if catkin_tools has anything to do with it, I did not want to mess with the catkin configurations without knowing how to reverse any effect... I do have a full ws that needs to operate in parallel with that nodelet.

Many thanks in advance,
Steve

EDIT:
Apparently I was supposed to install all kinds of prerequisites not mentioned in the instructions. Then the msgs package passed compilation but the driver failed because warnings were treated as errors. I added a -Wno-error flag in the Cmakelists and it passed the compilation until the linking, where it failed because of a missing boost declaration or something.

The thing is, if I delete the build and devel folders and try to recompile the whole ws, I get a boost library error when compiling the velodyne package, way before getting to the novatel package (this did not happen before).
Removing the libboost-all-dev would delete a long list of ros dependencies..... how do I get out of this one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278453/nodelet-crashes-at-launch/) by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2017-12-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-31**:
The `ERROR` you show is not a crash, the nodelet can't be found, so isn't even started (hard to crash without starting it).

> I built it using catkin_create_pkg + catkin_make

this confuses me: what did you use `catkin_create_pkg` for? The pkg already exists, why create one?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-31**:
In addition to what @gvdhoorn said, the README says to use `catkin_tools` to compile. You should follow the instructions in the README.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-01**:
@jayess: `catkin_tools` 'just' adds some convenience to the whole process. Building with `catkin_make` will not alter the outcome (ie: the produced binaries and other derived artefacts).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-01**:
@StevenCoral: am I correct in assuming that you copied some files from the repository into a new pkg (created using `catkin_create_pkg`) and then tried to build your workspace? That wouldn't work, no.

Also: ignoring errors like you are doing is probably not a good idea.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-01**:
If we want to be correct about it, you should post a quick answer to your own question (something along the lines of "I hadn't followed the instructions correctly, which lead to all sorts of problems. Now it builds, but I have problems with Boost". Accept that and then post a new question for ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-01**:
.. your Boost problems.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-01**:
Finally: if you (cross-)post things to issue trackers, please always mention that to keep discussions/troubleshooting sessions connected: [swri-robotics/novatel_gps_driver#13](https://github.com/swri-robotics/novatel_gps_driver/issues/13).

**Comment by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on 2018-01-01**:
The package thing was a mistake. I have read that catkin build and catkin_make are not compatible when it comes to build/devel content. When you try to use catkin build it alerts you to delete the catkin_make folders you might have. And the fact is, it did not build a lot of stuff catkin_make did.

**Comment by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on 2018-01-01**:
My question was to get my workspace back, not about boost, because it is unrelated to this board. Had to reinstall ROS (not 2 much trouble). I did not post my issue here because I dont want to hassle more than needed - I figure the people who wrote the nodelet might know more.

**Comment by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on 2018-01-01**:
I dont always know the package name, a lot of times you need to guess the combination (except the ros-indigo- part) unless it is given to you by the distributors. and they only instructed about source build, which I usually try to avoid...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-01**:\

> I dont always know the package name, a lot of times you need to guess the combination

this confuses me: debian pkg name is *always* `ros-$distro-` and then the name of the package with all underscores replaced with dashes (ie: `-`). There isn't much to guess there ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-01**:\

> I have read that catkin build and catkin_make are not compatible when it comes to build/devel content.

The only thing you can't do is use `catkin_make` *after* you've used `catkin_tools` and vice-versa. In all other cases they should result in the same artefacts being generated. If they ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-01**:
.. don't, that would be a bug and should be reported.

Anecdotal, but I use `catkin_tools` and `catkin_make` both daily, and they have their quirks, but in the end it doesn't matter which one builds what (as long as you are consistent).

**Comment by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on 2018-01-02**:
unfortunately, I am a mere engineer and not a software developer, so a lot of the compiling environment is like voodoo to me. Anyway, the package seemed to install using apt-get, I hope it would work when I get the chance to check it on the RTK itself. How do I tag your comment as the answer?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-02**:\

> How do I tag your comment as the answer?

we can't.

I've converted the most relevant comment into an answer. You should be able to accept that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not really an answer (as we don't solve your specific question), but: it looks like `novatel_gps_driver` has been released ([wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/novatel_gps_driver)). Installation should then be as simple as `sudo apt install ros-$distro-novatel-gps-driver`.

Do you have a specific reason for wanting to build from source?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StevenCoral](https://answers.ros.org/users/30608/stevencoral/) on 2018-01-02**:
I count this as solving my problem of installing the novatel Driver. Thanks!